# OpenCV issue with M1 Mac: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have been used this code to adjust image alignment in Windows machines and raspberry pi without any problem. But when I recently changed to M1 based macbook, I got an error of 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'CFIgray' referenced before assignment'. I changed my environment with Anaconda, Spyder, and OpenCV since initially I assumed that this is derived from compatibility between programming software and M1 mac. But it turns a problem with my function code 'Img_Alignment'. Would you give me advices to solve this issue? If the code of 'Img_Alignment' always causes an issue, I can take off this with alternative method, which can adjust alignment of image based on a reference image. Look forward to hearing any advices!

```
import csv
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import glob
import pandas as pd

#function to adjust alignment of unaliment image
def Img_Alignment(Image_for_alignment,Reference):
    #the referecen: https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/
    #1st parameter -> Image_for_alignment: an image that should be adjusted
    #2nd parameter -> Reference: a reference alignment image for alignment adjustment
    Before = cv2.imread(Image_for_alignment)#Read image that is before the alignment adjustment
    Before_gray = cv2.cvtColor(Before,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert the image as gray scale
    sz = Reference.shape #find size of the reference image
    warp_mode = cv2.MOTION_TRANSLATION # Define the motion model
    # Define 2x3 or 3x3 matrices and initialize the matrix to identity
    if warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY:
        warp_matrix = np.eye(3, 3, dtype=np.float32)
    else:
        warp_matrix = np.eye(2, 3, dtype=np.float32)
    # Specify the number of iterations.
    number_of_iterations = 5000;
    # Specify the threshold of the increment
    # in the correlation coefficient between two iterations
    termination_eps = 1e-10;
    # Define termination criteria
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, number_of_iterations,  termination_eps)
    # Run the ECC algorithm. The results are stored in warp_matrix.
    (cc, warp_matrix) = cv2.findTransformECC(Reference,Before_gray,warp_matrix, warp_mode, criteria, None, 1)
    if warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY :
        # Use warpPerspective for Homography
        Aligned = cv2.warpPerspective (Before, warp_matrix, (sz[1],sz[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
    else:
    # Use warpAffine for Translation, Euclidean and Affine
        Aligned = cv2.warpAffine(Before, warp_matrix, (sz[1],sz[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
    Aimg=str(Image_for_alignment).replace('.png','')
    cv2.imwrite(Aimg+"_aligned.jpg",Aligned)#it generates 16 bit images

#Index Extractor based on Multispectral Images
#User defined function to creat index image and extract the average and std of the index value over the projected canopy size
def IEMI(imageformat, folder):
    path = glob.glob(folder+"/*/")#directory 
    path = (pd.Series(path) + imageformat).tolist()#find all files in a folder of the directory
    
    for i in path:
        fileList=glob.glob(i)
        for fdx, filename in enumerate(fileList): #A For loop statment: iteration from all indices (filenames) within the folder
            fname = filename.rsplit(".", 1)[0] #Treating the string into a list following the separator "."
            fname = fname.replace('ch7', '')#remove string that is redundant 
            fname = fname.replace('mask', '')#remove string that is redundant
            if filename.find('mask')!= -1:#mask = Chlorophyll fluorescence image used to generate mask image
                CFIimg = cv2.imread(filename) #Define 'CFIimg' that reads an CFI image corresponding to a filename;
                CFIgray = cv2.cvtColor(CFIimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#Convert 'CFIimg' as grayscale image
            
            elif filename.find('ch6')!= -1:#ch6 = 870 nm, here the program fix the alignment
                Img_Alignment(filename, CFIgray)#CFIgray)
                Pch6 = cv2.imread(fname+"_aligned.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH) #open 16 bit image (the aligned image) as 8 bit image

IEMI('/*.png',"/Users/Desktop/picture")
```

Comment: The error is clear. You are assuming that `CFIgray = cv2.cvtColor(CFIimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` will be executed before `Img_Alignment(filename, CFIgray)#CFIgray)`  but nothing guarantees that this will happen.

Comment: Did you try, for example, copying and pasting `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'CFIgray' referenced before assignment` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=UnboundLocalError%3A+local+variable+%27CFIgray%27+referenced+before+assignment)?

Comment: I went through previous posts or any other documents in a search engine but they always talked about declaring a variable of integer. However, my case is declaring a variable of NumPy array (image) and I have no idea how to do that (please bear with me, because I am a very entry-level python user and I learned everything from scratches and searcing...). Besides, this issue never happened when I used it with Windows machine., which makes me quite confused.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with this block of code

```
if filename.find('mask')!= -1:#mask = Chlorophyll fluorescence image used to generate mask image
                CFIimg = cv2.imread(filename) #Define 'CFIimg' that reads an CFI image corresponding to a filename;
                CFIgray = cv2.cvtColor(CFIimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#Convert 'CFIimg' as grayscale image
            
elif filename.find('ch6')!= -1:#ch6 = 870 nm, here the program fix the alignment
                Img_Alignment(filename, CFIgray)#CFIgray)
                Pch6 = cv2.imread(fname+"_aligned.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH) #open 16 bit image (the aligned image) as 8 bit image
```

If the first if statement isn't evaluated, the variable CFIgray is never assigned. Then with your elif, you refer to it, even though you never instanciated the variable.

Comment: Actually, I cannot get rid of these 'if' or 'elif' statements since an image with a certain character should be treated at a time. Would you give me an advice to declare a variable in which NumPy array? I searched similar issues but they usually talk about integer variable, which is not my case.